# email notification for low disk space alert (if disk space is less than 10-20 %) on AWS windows and Db server

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do you setup email notification for low disk space alert (if disk space is <10-20%)on Aws Windows and Db server by using cloudwatch?

Let me know the possibilities that how to do and what to do for this setup.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon provides scripts so you can add memory and disk space alerts to Linux instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html). They don't appear to do so for windows, but [here's a third-party script that handles that](https://github.com/eleven41/CloudWatchMonitor).

[Many shops use NewRelic for more advanced monitoring.](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-windows/installation-configuration/installing-servers-windows)

Comment: Thanks tedder it worked for windows and i am working on Linux server when i am trying to execute this command   "./mon-get-instance-stats.pl --recent-hours=12" it was showing me the error can you please let me know how to move forward from here.

Comment: error:[ec2-user@ip-123.12.12.12 aws-scripts-mon]$ ./mon-get-instance-stats.pl --recent-hours=12

Instance i-796a1df8 statistics for the last 12 hours.

ERROR: Failed to initialize: No IAM role is associated with this EC2 instance.